# Copy Postgres Data into Excel

Tags: excel, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have 100+ databases and need to export ~10 rows out of each, I know how to export them into CSV but I don't want 100+ different CSV files and I don't want to manually copy and paste them all into a CSV file.

Is there a way to run a script on multiple database that will append a CSV through PgAdmin to save some time.

This is kind of what I am referring to:
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/export-postgresql-table-to-csv-file/

I want something like this but to just add more rows instead of overwriting it with every export.

Comment: Each of the tables only has ~10 rows, or you only want to extract ~10 rows out of each?  If the latter, what is the critera to only extract those few?

Comment: Also, do you want them on 100 different sheets or all on the same sheet?

Comment: Each table has 1,000+ rows but I have a select, something like `SELECT "Name","Email" FROM "Users" WHERE "Enabled" = true`,  that narrows it down to the ~10 that I want. And I want them all on the same sheet.